# How to use variables in python-gql?

Tags: graphql, graphql-python

This function will return all users instead of the giving username, how could I make it right? And any better GraphQL client for Python? gql just so simple that no much documents could check.

```
    def fetch_user(username):
        query = gql("""
                    query getUser($username: String) {
                    user(
                        where: { name: { _eq: $username } }
                    ) {
                        id
                        name
                    }
                    }
                """)
        result = client.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use variables in [graphql-python/gql](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql) with the help of `variable_values` parameter.
Here is a code snippet in which I have used the variable.

```
query = gql("""
mutation ($paramId: ID!, $paramTitle: String!){
    XputPost(id: $paramId, title: $paramTitle){
        id
        title
    }
}
""")

params = {
    "paramId": "1",
    "paramTitle": "New Post"
}
result = client.execute(query, variable_values=params)
```

I hope this answer helps you.